# How to get a part of string with regular expression

Tags: regex, split, alteryx

I am working with Alteryx and I really have troubles writing regular expressions.

**My data sample:**

```
/abc/04. bcc/cc
/ab bn/uat/ab
/abnm ag/adgr gada/rfd/dfd/cv
```

I need two regular expression sentences to get the part of string in the first / / and the other in the second / / in two separate columns.

**Desired result:**

**First column:**

```
abc
ab bn
abnm
```

**Second column:**

```
04. bcc
uat
adgr gada
```

Comment: What's you budget? I might be able to give you a two-for-one discount.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: If it is that simple you should probably use a function to split strings into parts (like javascript `str.split('/')` or PHP `explode('/', $str)`) I don't know alteryx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Text to Column" tool for that:
[image]

Use `/` as a delimiter and get rid of the columns you don't need afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! I didn`t even thought it could be done in the easier way.